# phonegap android softkeybord plugin to specify numeric keypad

Tags: android, cordova, plugins, keyboard

Please help me in solving the problem with android app. When I use a input field with type="number" - and it works fine, when the user clicks on the field, the screen displays a numeric keyboard. But when I add the autofocus to the input field, there is only the standard text keyboard using softkeybord show plugin. In this case, click on the input field is triggering numeric keyboard. Please help me make that when I install the autofocus, input field appear exactly the numeric keyboard.
I installed the autofocus to the input field and called show method of softkeybord plugin which gives me alphanumeric keypad.What change in plugin should I do so that will give me numeric keypad.

Below is the code snippet for show method:

```
    public void showKeyBoard() {
    InputMethodManager mgr = (InputMethodManager) Constants.mContext
            .getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);

    mgr.showSoftInput(webView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

    EditText e = new EditText(Constants.mContext);
    e.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
    webView.addView(e);

    ((InputMethodManager) Constants.mContext.getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE)).showSoftInput(webView, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);

}
```

Comment: I don't think autofocus is reliable across all devices. A better option would be to find the keyboard plugin that allows you to show the keyboard after a timeout period 1/2 a second....